# Why is an Angular form VALID with no mat-error when it has formGroup.errors?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm using reactive forms and a custom validator in Angular 11. I want to flag an error at the form level when the user selects an `EndDate` that is earlier than the `StartDate`. I'll use this form-level error to display error text on the template as well as to disable the button to submit the form.

There seem to be two issues here that I can't figure out:

**1. When I set an error via the customValidator on the form, the `form.status` remains `VALID` even when there are `form.errors`. Why is this?**

**2. In the template, checking the form's errors doesn't work. I have a `mat-error` with `form.hasErrors('endDateTooSoon')`, and yet this error never displays. What am I missing here? Something odd.**

This is the form instantiation.

```
  shiftEditorForm = new FormGroup({
    shiftTitle: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    shiftStartDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    shiftStartTime: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    shiftEndDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    shiftEndTime: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  }, DateValidators.compareDates('shiftStartDate', 'shiftEndDate', { endDateTooSoon: true})
 );
```

This is the validator:

```
  static compareDates = (
    dateField1: string,
    dateField2: string,
    validatorField: { [key: string]: boolean }): ValidatorFn => {
      return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      const date1 = control.get(dateField1)?.value;
      const date2 = control.get(dateField2)?.value;
      if (date1 && date2 && date1 > date2) {
        return validatorField;
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

This is what the form looks like when the validator works:

[image]

(Why is it VALID when an error has been correctly added? )

This is the template block defining the `shiftStartDate` formControl:

```
<mat-form-field class="date-selection"
    appearance="outline">
  <input matInput
    [matDatepicker]="startDate"
    formControlName="shiftStartDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #startDate></mat-datepicker>
  <mat-error *ngIf="shiftStartDate?.touched && !shiftStartDate?.value">
    Shift start date is required.
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="shiftEditorForm?.hasError('endDateTooSoon')">
    End date must be after start date.
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I'm checking with `*ngIf="shiftEditorForm.hasError()` and yet it never displays the error.

There's another similar block of the template for the `shiftEndDate` formControl.

And yet here as I manipulate the datepickers, and set the `shiftEndDate` to be before the `shiftStartDate`, nothing happens and the error doesn't display:

[image: No errors appearing]

**Update:** An added wrinkle I found after posting this question. The button to submit the form **IS** disabled/enabled based on validity of the date check, with the following attribute on the `button`: `[disabled]="this.shiftEditorForm.invalid"`. Real head-scratcher here: the formGroup shows status as `VALID` but is returning true for this `invalid` boolean check.

Comment: Instead of declaring it on the constructor, try using `setValidators()`. Something like `shiftEditorForm.setValidators(DateValidators.compareDates('shiftStartDate', 'shiftEndDate', { endDateTooSoon: true}));`

Comment: I tried that. Same result.

Comment: You are returning the `validatorField` as a result of your validator.  Shouldn't this  be returning a ValidationErrors object?

Comment: I'm returning the third parameter of the validator function, which is `{ endDateTooSoon: true}` an object suitable for ValidationError.

Comment: Form validators never worked for me like this. I have to wrap them into an options object like `{validators: [yourValidator]}`. I place this where you defined your form validator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problems

I think I have been able to reproduce your issue in this [stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jpcxfu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I have noticed two things,

1. Your have not considered time in your validation
2. As stated in your question, validation errors are not showing...

The Second error is what we will try to look at

### Problem Analysis

To understand the problem I will state that your code works totally a expected...

Below should explain it all

Add below code under the `<mat-error></mat-error>` tag

```html
<span *ngIf="shiftEditorForm?.hasError('endDateTooSoon')">
    End date must be after start date.
</span>
```

You will notice that this is being shown without any issues when the date error is thrown

Simply, for `mat-error` to show, then the `input` associated with that `<mat-error>` must have an error. From the form we notice that the `shiftStartDate` becomes valid once a user enters a value so `<mat-error>` will not be shown, totally as expected

### Solution to your problem

If you need to show the `mat-error` then you will need to set the control to invalid e.g with

```typescript
 control.get(dateField1)?.setErrors({higherThanStart: true})
```

Your `validatorFn` will be something like

```typescript
class DateValidators {
    static compareDates = (
    dateField1: string,
    dateField2: string,
    validatorField: { [key: string]: boolean }): ValidatorFn => {
      return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      const date1 = control.get(dateField1)?.value;
      const date2 = control.get(dateField2)?.value;
      if (date1 && date2 && date1 > date2) {
         control.get(dateField1)?.setErrors({higherThanStart: true}) 
        return validatorField;
      }
      
      control.get(dateField1)?.setErrors({higherThanStart: null})
      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

Now the Error will show... [See Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dtnvew?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks @Owen Kelvin! Yes, these are the two issues. I made the same realizations last night but I'm giving you the checkmark because of all your work! The mat-error issue and the input-level validation needed inside the validator. Plus, you pointed out one thing I missed, which is to `setErrors({ error: false})` rather than `setErrors(null)` in the valid case, which I had done.

Comment: Actually, using `setErrors` with the error object set to `false` does not work to remove the `mat-error`. Need to stay with `null`.

Comment: @TonyBrasunas yes it should be null not false

Answer (score 0):

**It turns out there are two issues here.**

1. `mat-error` elements will **only display if** there is an *input-level error* on the field -- it has to be an error on the individual formControl. So when you do an `*ngIf` on the `mat-input` it has to be in addition to the implicit ngIf that exists to check that there is an error on that form-field. This is why `*ngIf="shiftEditorForm?.hasError('')"` didn't work. There was no error set on the formControl at the input level, so even when there was an error on the formGroup set via the validator the `mat-error` never displayed.
2. Attaching the validator at the formGroup level will *can* check multiple fields in the formControl, which is necessary here, but the validator's return values (the `error` object or `null`) will only apply to the formGroup and not to any individual formControl inputs. Thus the need to manually use `setErrors({ [error]: true })` on the individual date formControls as well as return the error on the form itself.

Here is the validator code:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

export class DateValidators {

  static checkDateRange (
    dateField1: string,
    dateField2: string,
    error: string
  ): ValidatorFn {
      return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      const date1 = control.get(dateField1);
      const date2 = control.get(dateField2)
      if (date1?.value && date2?.value && date1?.value > date2?.value) {
        date1.setErrors({ [error]: true })
        date2.setErrors({ [error]: true })
        return { [error]: true };
      }
      date1?.setErrors(null);
      date2?.setErrors(null);
      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

And here is how to attach it to the formGroup:

```
DateValidators.checkDateRange('startDate', 'endDate', 'endDateTooSoon');
```

The first two parameters are the names of the formControl inputs. The third is the name of the error to be attached and checked in the template.

After I figured this out, I thought I would post a succinct answer. Owen figured it out as well at the same time, and I marked his answer correct as he lays this all out quite well. I just wanted to add a summary.